# Need query help, either removing results from one query from another one, or more specific select

Tags: sql

```sql
SELECT tokenID FROM tokenRefs WHERE NOT tokenRefNameID = 4
```

| tokenID | tokenRefNameID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 |

I need to select all tokenIDs that do not have tokenRefNameID = 4. However, there are multiple tokenRefNameIDs that can be used for the same tokenID.

I tried using the above query to select which aren't tokenRefNameID = 4 and then I wanted to subtract or delete the tokenIDs that have =4 from those query results but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Repeating yourself doesn't help us understand the question; please don't just copy the content from the top textbox to the bottom to get paste the wizard, *read* the content it presents to you. You should really have taken the [tour] too, you were prompted to when you signed up today, but you didn't.

Comment: I've also removed the conflicting tags here;  please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Answer (score 1):

This is for mysql, but it would work on any Database system.

What you are searching for is `EXISTS`, that  would check if for every tokenID the condition is = 4 is valid, and apply it to every row, so that the contnt of the row is not rekevant

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE tokenRefs (
  `tokenID` INTEGER,
  `tokenRefNameID` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO tokenRefs
  (`tokenID`, `tokenRefNameID`)
VALUES
  ('1', '4'),
  ('2', '4'),
  ('1', '2');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT tokenID FROM tokenRefs t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tokenRefs WHERE tokenRefNameID  = 4 AND t1.tokenID = tokenID);
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Ah. Yes. `EXISTS` could be used as well. Its performance can be a little better, but it is a little harder to read as well.

Comment: @BartHofland not in is very slow , and it is as good to read like existsis

Comment: @nbk You are right. And `NOT IN` can also be tricky when NULLs are involved. So in general your solution is indeed more correct than mine.

Answer (score 0):

A `SELECT` query  returns all *rows* that meet the criteria in its `WHERE` clause. In this case, your query will return all rows where `tokenRefNameID` is not 4. (By the way, for numerical values you could also use `tokenRefNameID <> 4` instead of `NOT tokenRefNameID = 4`.)

So with your provided sample data, your query will return `tokenID` value 1, because there exists a row in table `tokenRefs` where `tokenID` has value 1 and `tokenRefNameID` has value 2. And that is a valid row for your query.

If you want to get only `tokenID` values that do not occur in rows together with `tokenRefNameID` value 4, you need a slightly other approach:

1. Create a query to select the `tokenID` values that exist in combination with `tokenRefName` value 4.
2. Use the query from step 1 as a subquery within a query that will select only the other `tokenID` values in the table.

The query in step 1 will probably be something like:

```sql
SELECT tokenID
FROM   tokenRefs
WHERE  tokenRefNameID = 4;
```

The final query in step 2 could use an `IN` clause:

```sql
SELECT tokenID
FROM   tokenRefs
WHERE  tokenID NOT IN (--Query from step 1
                       SELECT tokenID
                       FROM   tokenRefs
                       WHERE  tokenRefNameID = 4);
```

Comment: Thank you! That make so much more sense. I was having trouble wrapping my head around subqueries without context of my database!